# django registration - allows multiple users for an email id

Tags: django, django-models, django-registration

I am trying out django-registration. I found that it allows multiple registration for same emailid. I want to prevent that. What is the best way to do that?

ok, I see there is a subclass RegistrationFormUniqueEmail. Now, how to use this class? I changed this

```
    def get_form_class(self, request):

    return RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
```

But, it must be better to change this from my application rather than in source code. So, how do I do that?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've added `registration` to your settings file, you can use the form in your views.py like so:

`from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail`

`form = RegistrationFormUniqueEmail()`

That's it. That will give you the form that you need and will take care of the unique email validation.

Comment: Its not working for me. I tried the above code as well as tried by return RegistrationFormUniqueEmail() in __init__.py in backends